# Why do I have to import java.util.List when I already imported java.util.*?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

In Eclipse, I'm trying to make an array list.

```
List<Object> al = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

It gives me an error and says I should import java.util.List

I already imported java.util.*.

Is this a problem?

Comment: no its not . r u sure ?

Comment: I think it's not an error it's a warning. And it is also a better practice to not use `import java.util.*`.

Comment: it never says so: http://ideone.com/pJANcN

Comment: did you forget the semi-colon

Comment: I think the error is wrong: if you imported  java.util.*, there should be no need to import List separately.

Comment: 100% sure. i got java.util.*

Comment: Can you show the error message?

Comment: Can you post your full code?

Comment: Is it possible that you have other imported `List` class like from `java.awt` or maybe you have your own `List` class created in same package your current class is placed? In that case you would see error claiming that `The type List is ambiguous` and you should explicitly show which list you want to use.

Answer (score 4):

Once you import `java.util.*`, you should not have to import `java.util.List` or `java.util.ArrayList`. On the other hand, it is considered bad practice to do a star import because it dramatically increases the probability of a name clash. It is better to import each class you are using from a different package independently. That is what Eclipse is probably trying to tell you.

Comment: What you say is true however I doubt Eclipse is trying to tell op that due to Eclipse having the behavior that when you type imports and allow auto-complete to finish, it will do a star import.

Comment: @BobbyDigital That depends on the version of Eclipse and how it is configured.